# Fitting data for D3 graph to create legend

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a data variable which contains the following:

```
  [Object { score="2.8",  word="Blue"}, Object { score="2.8",  word="Red"}, Object { score="3.9",  word="Green"}]
```

I'm interested in modifying a piece of a D3 graph http://bl.ocks.org/3887051 to display the legend, which would be the list of the "word", for my data set.

The legend script looks like this (from link above):

```
var ageNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; });

var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(ageNames.slice().reverse())
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width - 24)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

How do I modify their ageNames function to display the "word" set from my data? I'm not sure how they're utilizing the d3.keys. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work more or less, but you may need to `reverse()` (as the original example does) or otherwise rearrange the elements of `words`, in order to correctly map a word to the right color. Depends on how you've implemented your graph.

```
var words = yourDataArray.map(function(entry) { return entry.word; });

var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(words)
// The rest stays the same
```